# How do you get multiple rows of tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Is there any way to get Google Chrome to use multiple rows for tabs?

I haven't been able to find an extension, or a mention of this feature coming up in a future release.

Comment: I opened an issue at chrome bug tracker, everyone who's interested can go vote/comment this issue up and help bring this  issue to the dev team's attention: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696347

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In short, you can't, and it doesn't seem to be coming. I'm guessing they're trying to teach you good tab management and to <s>let</s> make you play with the tab ripping.
There are many alternative solutions to tab overload though. Take a look at [TooManyTabs](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp).

Comment: TooManyTabs seems like a pretty weird solution, but it could help. I'd rather have multliple rows. I guess extensions can't mess with the tab bar.

Comment: Extensions can't mess with the tab bar, yes. The Chrome extension framework is almost entirely iframes and javascript. I don't think Chrome will ever get multiple rows because 1) it would be a UI nightmare the way they designed it, and 2) there are two solutions out there already (vertical tabs, tab ripping)

Comment: +1 for the vertical tabs! Except for some reason I cant scroll vertically at all when I get too many tabs... And there's no way to resize the tab bar horizontally so I can hardly read any of the titles :/

Comment: Now, two years later, it's still does not seem to be coming. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132246

Comment: Firefox it is then.

Comment: zespri: That issue is about the bookmark bar, not tabs... o_O

Comment: I came across this question when I was looking for a way of showing the tabs in Chrome in more than one line, only to find out that even almost 7 years after this question was originally asked, there is still no way of doing that, and right now it looks like there is not going to be one... However, there are a few quite neat extensions that deal with tabs, like Tab Manager and others... worth a try looking for those in the Chrome Store. Happy Chroming... :)

Comment: I know that there are other solutions, etc. But, man, I just want multiple tab rows. As simple as that. That's the way I need, like, and prefer - despite all the different opinions. Am I asking for too much?

Comment: Can't someone fork Chromium and implement it in the browser or something?

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [TabsOutliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) extension.
It gives you editable overview of all the windows and tabs in Chrome.
Here is a screenshot:

[image: TabsOutliner extension]

Comment: I personally use tabsoutliner, but the developer's been requesting compensation with progressively more aggressive methods. Currently they want $15 to unlock some 'features' that were previously free, such as right clicking in the listing window and selecting "Save As" (Right click is now disabled... But Ctrl-S still works... >.< )

Comment: this one is better than TooManyTabs

Answer (score 2):

A work around would be to use pin tabs. If you right click a tab and choose `pin` it will become a small button to the very left. Also, it'll stay there when you close your browser and open it again.

Doesn't solve the problem but you'll at least get a better overview of your tabs

Answer (score 0):

"tree style tabs" is a good alternative, I just miss a shortcut hotkey to open it instead of clicking on its icon.. also options to enlarge the list.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tree-style-tabs-beta/ffididlaalcoegfcalmeldjfnihmoech

I miss also at pin tabs, an option to make the pinned smaller, so there could have more!, the width of the page icon is good enough, actually it occupies twice that size :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there a way currently for having rows of tabs in Chrome.
However - If you want a way to view or search your open tabs then you can use a short cut

`shift + cmd + a`

this will bring a side bar where you can search and go to the tab you are interested.
It will even list tabs that have been recently closed.

[image: SEARCH TABS]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to get multiple rows of tabs, but I think **the best alternative is tab groups**.  Just right click any of your tabs, and look for the ["Add tab to group"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcJ4L.png) option.  I tend to use tab groups for all of the tabs that I rarely close.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tab Groups Extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tab-groups-extension/nplimhmoanghlebhdiboeellhgmgommi) , it handles built in Chrome tab groups, and also allows for rules to be set (E.G. add anything containing Youtube or Netflix to "@Media" group). Great looking UI, only thing that is missing is Seach.

Also works great with [Previous tab](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/previous-tab/bjaniflnlhhofabpoamhnobeonjcjjpl), as this one allows you to switch between current tab and last tab. Would be nice to have a longer tab history.

I also use [Swith workstation](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/switch-workstation-tab-ma/foilkalbafoifklkphdkijdcnkgcjefn) as this is a sidebar that allows you to see your tabs grouped by source site. It allows you to close all Youtube tabs open for example. Would be nice if you had the option to close all except 1.